# Morphism from image to kernel for a complex of objects in an abelian category.

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I'm back again with another basic category theory question. I promise I will get my head around this - one day.

Consider a complex (so $f_{n}\circ f_{n-1}=0$), of objects in an abelian category:
$$
\cdots\xrightarrow{f_{n-2}} A^{n-1}\xrightarrow{f_{n-1}}A^{n}\xrightarrow{f_{n}}A^{n+1}\xrightarrow{f_{n+1}}\cdots
$$
We then have morphisms $\text{im}(f_{n-1}):L^{n}\to A^{n}$, and $\text{ker}(f_{n}):K^{n}\to A^{n}$.

I want to show the existence of a morphism $k:L^{n}\to K^{n}$, which is then used for defining the cohomology of the complex.

The obvious thing to do is to apply the universal property of $\text{ker}(f_{n})$ to the morphism $\text{im}(f_{n-1}):L^{n}\to A^{n}$. This then reduces the problem to showing that  $f_{n}\circ\text{im}(f_{n-1})=0$. This obviously follows from $f_{n}\circ f_{n-1}=0$ in concrete examples, but I have been unable to show that this holds in general.

Again, this is probably trivial, but I have been trying to get my head around this for ages. Any help would be musch appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to show that the factorisation into the image in an abelian category is actually into an *epimorphism* followed by an monomorphism. This is in fact needed in the classical context too though it is so obvious we generally do not pay attention to it. It is not entirely trivial because of the use of this claim, at least from the looks of the way I am approaching it.

I do not know what your familiarity with category theory is but the proof of the result I claim—that any morphism factors through an epimorphism by its image in abelian categories—is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)

It is stated in terms of equalizers but abelian categories have equalizers: the equalizer of $(\alpha,\beta)$ is the kernel of $\alpha-\beta$. I was not able to find a much easier argument than the one on Wikipedia in the context of abelian categories on my own though I am less familiar with abelian categories than I probably should be.

Now to your point, factor $f_{n-1}$ as $f_{n-1}=i\circ p$ where $i:L^n\rightarrow A^n$ is the image morphism and $p$ is an epimorphism according to the above claim. Then since $f_n\circ f_{n-1}=0$ by assumption, $$(f_n\circ i)\circ p=0=0\circ p$$ so that, since $p$ is an epimorphism, $f_n\circ i=0$ as required.

Also, “philosophically”—but this is an actual theorem!—, we know that results that hold in traditional abelian categories by diagram-chasing also hold in more exotic—in fact arbitrary—abelian categories thanks to a nifty theorem by Freydd and Mitchell which essentially tells you that you can think of any (small) abelian category as a subcategory of the category of modules over a (possibly non-commutative) ring in such a way that kernels and cokernels, thus images, coimages, etc, are what you think they are, which is useful  since the result you were trying to prove is obvious in modules over a ring as you note; thus the general case usually follows from the case of modules over a ring for such results. You can learn about it here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Believe it or not, I had made it all the way up to the factorisation, but hadn't realised I could "cancel", $p$! I am slowly starting to get a feeling for category theoretic arguments, and your answer has helped to speed along that process.

Comment: You are welcome!